# Date in model binding is being set as American format even though culture is set as British in .net core 2.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

Model binding for date  in .net core 2.1 is setting date value in American format even though culture info is set as British format.

Any idea ?

Here is my startup file code snippet

```
 var  enGbCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = enGbCulture;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = enGbCulture;

            app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(enGbCulture),

                SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { enGbCulture },

                SupportedUICultures = new List < CultureInfo > { enGbCulture },
                RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
                    {
                    new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider { },
                    new CookieRequestCultureProvider { },
            },
            });
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

and below is  printing correct culture info in view

```
 <div>Current Culture: @CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DisplayName</div>
 <div>Current UI Culture: @CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DisplayName</div>
 <div>Current Thread Culture: @Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DisplayName;</div>
```

as 
[image]

## [Sample Project is on GitHub](https://github.com/nabinkjha/DateTimeLocalization)

Answer (score 0):

Just show your date in the format you want on the frontend after you will get the date from any input field just convert it to British format.

Try this code to change the date format.

```
 string date = model.DateOfBirth.tostring(); 
    //convert datetime to string and pass it to following code
    DateTime.ParseExact(date, "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score -1):

Raised this issue in GitHub [CaseRaisedInGitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8159) and created a demo project to explain the issue as well at
https://github.com/nabinkjha/DateTimeLocalization/tree/master/GetSearchDemo

[DemoProjectLink](https://github.com/nabinkjha/DateTimeLocalization/tree/master/GetSearchDemo)